# TukeyHSD not applicable to ANCOVA with factor, integer and numeric variables?

Tags: r

Ran an ANCOVA in r. Cannot successfully execute a TukeyHSD() on the data set since it has a range of variable types (factorial, integer and numeric).

I've tried converting all variables into factors, still no luck. The data set is listed below, followed by my code for a two-way ANCOVA. My aim was to assess the individual and combined effects of treatment (food type) and time (time required to go from being a caterpillar to a pupa, in days), grouped by the covariate initial weight (initial weight of each individual caterpillar in the experiment).

```
> GM
      Trt     Larval.period   Initial.wt  Pupal.wt   Percent.weight.gain
1  Uninfested            14      0.181    0.294       62.43094
2  Uninfested            20      0.318    0.519       63.20755
3  Uninfested            18      0.218    0.527      141.74312
4  Uninfested            18      0.195    0.326       67.17949
5  Uninfested            26      0.250    0.511      104.40000
6  Uninfested            14      0.181    0.299       65.19337
7  Uninfested            22      0.213    0.584      174.17840
8  Uninfested            26      0.255    0.442       73.33333
9  Uninfested            20      0.236    0.481      103.81356
10 Uninfested            18      0.298    0.452       51.67785
11 Uninfested            18      0.295    0.418       41.69492
12 Uninfested            24      0.297    0.424       42.76094
13 Uninfested            20      0.342    0.481       40.64327
14 Uninfested            14      0.210    0.434      106.66667
15 Uninfested            22      0.212    0.352       66.03774
16 Uninfested            18      0.215    0.472      119.53488
17 Uninfested            14      0.227    0.380       67.40088
18 Uninfested            20      0.191    0.520      172.25131
19 Uninfested            26      0.175    0.668      281.71429
20 Uninfested            24      0.312    0.542       73.71795
21 Uninfested            14      0.215    0.391       81.86047
22   Infested            18      0.142    0.765      438.73239
23   Infested            18      0.347    0.844      143.22767
24   Infested            14      0.183    0.369      101.63934
25   Infested            16      0.207    0.384       85.50725
26   Infested            16      0.156    0.361      131.41026
27   Infested            16      0.181    0.340       87.84530
28   Infested            14      0.153    0.346      126.14379
29   Infested            26      0.135    0.632      368.14815
30   Infested            31      0.124    0.302      143.54839
31   Infested            18      0.166    0.337      103.01205
32   Infested            18      0.141    0.339      140.42553
33   Infested            18      0.125    0.355      184.00000
34   Infested            24      0.384    0.874      127.60417
35   Infested            18      0.129    0.262      103.10078
36   Infested            18      0.172    0.389      126.16279
37   Infested            24      0.115    0.488      324.34783
38   Infested            24      0.185    0.367       98.37838
39   Infested            26      0.128    0.463      261.71875
40   Infested            18      0.334    0.622       86.22754
41   Infested            16      0.204    0.345       69.11765
42   Infested            24      0.213    0.448      110.32864
43   Infested            26      0.207    0.934      351.20773
44   Infested            26      0.221    0.680      207.69231

ANCOVA  <-aov(Pupal.wt ~ Trt*Initial.wt*Larval.period, data = GM)

TukeyHSD(ANCOVA): Error in rep.int(n, length(means)) : unimplemented type 
'NULL' in 'rep3'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored: Initial.wt
2: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored: Larval.period
3: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored: Trt, Initial.wt
4: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored: Trt, Larval.period
5: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored: Initial.wt, Larval.period
6: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) :
  non-factors ignored: Trt, Initial.wt, Larval.period
```

Data set is listed at top.

Comment: The title of your question doesn't seem to match the actual question: the title is as though you're asking for help choosing a type of analysis, which is off topic for SO but on topic for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). The actual question looks like it's about data types...?

Comment: Either way, I can't reproduce the problem with the sample of data provided. If you've got `NULL` values like the error message implies, we'd need to see some of those in a sample to reproduce the error

Comment: @camille Thanks for taking a look at this; I added in the entire data set, so the ancova should wok and the tukey error message should pop up.

Comment: Reading this text version of your data with `read.table` and running the `aov`, I don't get an error. Unless there's a data types issue that isn't captured here (`dput` is very helpful for diagnosing such bugs), it seems like there's something else going on that makes this not reproducible